# How to say "desire of being loved, praised, etc." in latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, gerund

This is the first time I ask a question here. I am trying to translate into latin the phrase "the desire of being loved (or praised, respected, etc.)". If what is desired were in active voice ("the desire of loving", for example), I would use a gerund: "cupido/desiderium amandi". But it is in passive voice, and there is no "passive gerund". How can I translate it? Is it correct "cupido/desiderium ut amer"? Thank you very much.

PS. In case it is necessary: in fact, it is for the translation of a prayer: "From the desire of being loved (praised, respected, etc.) deliver us, Lord".

Answer (score 4):

There is a prayer called the Litany of Humilty, which has passive forms like this: *A desiderio, ut lauder, libera me Domine* (from the desire of being praised, free me O Lord.)

If you replace *lauder* with *amer*, I think you'll have something close to what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact this is the prayer that I'm trying to translate into latin, but the problem is that the latin text you give is not the original, but a very recent translation, and I am unsure whether that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that there is no such thing as a passive gerund, but there is the gerundive, which is always passive. *Desiderium ad me amandum* or *Desiderium ad me amandam* may work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. But wouldn't "Desiderium ad me amandum" mean "the desire of loving myself"? The subject of "amandum" wouls still be the one who desires.

Comment: @JuanG.C. An interesting point. Perhaps we are going about this all wrong and should try an approach which does not need *desiderio*. Would *ab desiderando amari* be at all idiomatic?

Comment: You are probably right. I can't see anything wrong with that construction, but I want to be sure. Perhaps I will create another question about it.