# Is the construction "a desiderando amari" correct in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, gerund

In a [previous question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/18988/how-to-say-desire-of-being-loved-praised-etc-in-latin) in this forum I asked how could "the desire of being loved" (as in the prayer "From the desire of being loved, deliver me, Lord"), and similar constructions, be translated into Latin. The best proposal I was given was *a desiderando amari* (*A desiderando amari, libera me, Domine*). But I am not sure if that construction is correct and proper in Latin. ¿Can a gerund have an infinitive (and a passive infinitive) as object? Thank you very much.